# Display content by taxonomy term, including sub-terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, routes

I'm looking at Drupal for the first time in a long time, with a view to using it in a project we're starting. This seems like a very simple question, but I'm struggling to find the answer.

If we have a taxonomy of website sections and associated sub-sections, like this:

```
News
    - Europe
    - America
    - etc
Products
    - Widgets
    - Doodahs
    - etc
```

If we have a menu linking to News it's easy to display content associated explicitly with that term, I'm not seeing how to include content associated with its sub-terms though. Is the conventional way of achieving this through...views?

Thanks,

Toby

**Update:** It looks like in previous versions of Drupal you could perhaps specify a term depth in your URLs. I guess this is what I'm after, but in Drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, Views is the way to do it, using a 'Filter criteria' of 'Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)'. If there's a simpler way do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

link- https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_block

Taxonomy Menu Block allows you to make blocks
containing unordered lists that represent the structure of
your vocabularies, creating a menu out of your
taxonomies (without using Drupal's menu system).
TMB combines the idea of Taxonomy menu with the
workings of Menu block :
Make multiple menus per vocabulary.
"Split" the taxonomy into different menus.
This allows, for example, the creation of one menu with
only the top items (parents) of a vocabulary and
another menu with only the sub-items (children).
Make a menu out of a specific branch of your
vocabulary only.
Follow the active trail, also for nodes coupled to a term
with a term reference field.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like an interesting module, I can't see that it answers my question though? I've played around with the configuration, but whatever I do if I click on 'News', for example, I don't see content associated with Europe, America, etc.

Comment: You should try nice menu module for it which will enable you to see the sub menu on hover

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/nice_menus‎

Comment: Still doesn't address my actual problem though, does it?